# REST endpoint working in SharePoint online and not in on premise

Tags: 2013, rest, attachments, sharepoint-on-prem

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/items?$select=Id,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles`

The above REST endpoint works in SharePoint online and we are able to fetch attachments but the same endpoint doesn't work for SharePoint 2013 on-premise enterprise version.

I get the following error.

`Bad request`

I get details when I drop `$select`  and use just expand as follows:

`/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('List')/items?$expand=AttachmentFiles`

But if I use this I cannot expand extended lookup fields in the same list as the fields are required to be added to `$select`

What could be the reason? Is there anything that I can do where I get both attachments and extended lookup using same query.

Comment: Could you provide more information about how it's not working? Is the page throwing an error, returning no data, or a 404?

Comment: I get a Bad request error in on-prem but the same query works fine in online.Does the same work at your on-prem?

Comment: Please update your question with that data. Also include what version of SharePoint you're using. That'll help get you a good answer.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: are you using the correct name /url?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the reason it doesn't work on on-premise is because it shouldn't work. 365 is much more forgiving about OData, like you don't need `odata=verbose;`, probably because of early access and compatibility with already built stuff. The thing is that OData doesn't let you do wildcard select on expanded properties, and for this to work you need that. This is two levels of arrays, think about it as selecting all lists, then all items for all lists, and then selecting properties in the items - not straight forward. As you probably know, if you drop the `$select` it works

Comment: Like you said it works when I drop '$select`. But I also want to expand lookups which requires the fields to be added to '$select'as well.

Comment: Yes that is true. One way I can think of to solve your problem is by parallel requests (yes it's not pretty, but at least you can use promises and request simultaneously, you can also get away with only two requests, one for attachments and another for lookups). Another solution is to use JSOM. We wrap our ClientContext in a promise and combine REST with JSOM fluently

Comment: ok. Could you please provide some reference on how it can be achieved?I need to access this data outside SharePoint. So the same approach will help?

Comment: Do you have SP1 installed? SP1 adds support for JSON light (which allows you to drop the `odata=verbose` that @eirikb mentioned), but you have to do some additional steps, as mentioned [here](http://spdoctor.net/Pages/article.aspx?name=using-json-in-sharepoint-server-2013).  It's possible the changes done to REST api include something to do with attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your REST call in my SharePoint 2013 Enterprise environment and it works correctly.

Make sure your list has attachments turned on. List Settings>Advanced Settings> Attachments.  Set to Enabled.

Make user the Title in the url correctly matches a list in your on-prem site.

Comment: Attachements is enabled and the Url is also correct.Like eirikb said I get attachmentFiles values when i drop `$select`  and use just expand as follows:`/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('List')/items?$expand=AttachmentFiles` .But if I use this I cannot expand extended lookup fields as the fields are required to be added to `$select`

Answer (score 0):

REST API calls for dealing with attachments is not consistent between SharePoint 2013 / On Premises and SharePoint Online.

**SharePoint Online**
Including *AttachmentFiles* in the `$select` and `$expand` collections is enough.  The *Attachment* field is automatically returned in the results set.

**SharePoint 2013 / On Premises**
You must include both *AttachmentFiles, Attachments* in the `$select` statement. The `$expand` collections must still contain *AttachmentFiles*.  This method is recommended if you'd like your REST call to run in both versions of SharePoint.