# "GetFolderById" available in REST API?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

is `GetFolderById` available in REST API- SharePoint 2013 on premises.

Comment: Check the answer here...https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119202/working-with-document-libraries-based-on-uniqueid-rest-api

Comment: You can use like this `/_api/web/GetFolderById('UniqueId')/Files/add(url='filename',overwrite=true)`

Comment: Kindly let me know if it is not working

Comment: Hardik did you try it? Looks like this endpoint is not available.

Comment: Can you please refer this as well?...https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137810/rest-endpoint-working-in-sharepoint-online-and-not-in-on-premise

Comment: @Hardik endpoint not available.